# How to Find string inside html tags in lua

Tags: lua

Using lua script I want to find sting inside string. 
This is how I am trying but not working.

```
local mystring="<span class="my-author"><a href="http://aaaa/author/abb-abbb/" title="Posts by abb" class="author" rel="author">abc xyz</a></span>"


local x, y= string.find(mystring,'<span class=\"my-author"\>')
local w, z = string.find(mystring,'</a></span>)
local author
if y==nil or w==nil then
    print(author)
else
    author = string.sub(mystring, y+1, w-1)
            print(author)
end
```

How do I find string inside `<span class>`.

Thanks,

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors, with `"` characters inside `"`-delimited strings and unfinished `'`-delimited strings. Does your problem persist after you fix the syntax errors?

Comment: It should be noted that the syntax error is so obvious that even Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter noticed it.

Comment: @hugomg, I do not see any syntax errors in my code, do you see any errors? if so let me know what are those?

Comment: If you try running the code you posted here Lua will point out the lines with syntax errors. Basically, you need to be careful when you want to include quote characters inside strings.

Comment: @hugomg, I ran this code it is working fine without any errors, it is printing empty value, not finding what I expect, all that I need is, how do I find string inside <span class>, other thing is, when I give local x, y= string.find(mystring,'<span class=') upto this, it is working. But I have so many span classes so I can't use that way.

Comment: The code you are running is clearly not the same code that you posted here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your `pater` in `find` will not get

> [... considered "magic" ...](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find)

```
local mystring='<span class="my-author"><a href="http://aaaa/author/abb-abbb/" title="Posts by abb" class="author" rel="author">abc xyz</a></span>'

local x, y = string.find(mystring,'<span class="my-author">', 0, true)
local w, z = string.find(mystring,'</a></span>', x, true)
local author
print(x,y,w,z)
if y==nil or w==nil then
    print(author)
else
    author = string.sub(mystring, y+1, w-1)
            print(author)
end
```

[Running example](http://ideone.com/2tbDWD)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakuje.. it is working fine.                                                local x, y = string.find(mystring,'<span class="my-author">', 0, true)
local w, z = string.find(mystring,'</a></span>', 0, true), I used zero(0) in this line, I understood what I have to use. Thanks once again...

Comment: I see you went through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, so I believe you know what to do with answers that solved your problems. Hint: There is the "tick" sing on the left.